# how to dynamically change the value of jquermobile datetime input

Tags: datetime, jquery-mobile

I want to change the datetime input area whith the jquery function val(), but it cannot work in iphone safari.
My code like this:

```html
<input type='datetime' data-clear-btn='true' name='datepicker' id='datepicker' placeholder='yy-mm-dd h:i' value="">
<a data-role='button' data-mini='true' data-inline='true' id='change' >change time</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#change").live("click",function(){
    $("#datepicker").val("2013-06-18");
})
</script>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jquery is 1.8.3 and mobile is 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your script for this example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#change").button().click(function() {
          $("#datepicker").val("2013-06-18");
    });
</script>
```